# How to manage nearly 5000 records in a for loop in node js server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb

I created a server using NodeJS. There's a database in MySQL and nearly 5000 users in it. I have to read the mysql database and update and make a log in MongoDB database. I implemented a code for this.
https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/aa9d6a511070c3c78ba3ebc018306ad8

Here's the problem. in this code, in line 50, I added this value.

```
userArray[i].ID]
```

This is a user ID from for loop and I need to update mysql table with that ID. All those codes in the for loop block. But I am getting this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

So that I assigned those values to variables at the top. See line 38 and 39.

```
var selectedUserID = userArray[i].ID;
                var selectedUserTelephone = userArray[i].telephone;
```

When I'm using like this, there's no error. But user ID is not updating. Recent 2 values has same user ID.

What is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general JavaScript issue related to the concepts of scope and hoisting of variables during asynchronous operations.

```
var a = 0;

function doThingWithA () {
  console.log(a)
}

for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  a++;
  setTimeout(function () {
    doThingWithA();
  }, 10);
}
```

In this example "a" will always log with a value of 1000. The reason for this is that the setTimeout (mimics the slow db operation) takes time and during that time (before the log happens) "a" is increased to 1000 since the for loop does not wait for setTimeout to complete.

The best solution is to use the "async" module.

```
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  connection.query(query, function (err, users) {
    async.eachSeries(users, function (user, next) {
      async.parallel([
        function updateUserStatus (cb) { /* your current code */ },
        function updateUserAccount (cb) { /* current code for this */ }
      ], next);
    }, function (err) { console.log('finished for all users!') })
  });
});
```

You could also use promises. This is a typical async issue in node.js. From reading your code it appears you think each operation runs in series, whereas in node each input/ouput (e.g db call) is triggered, but your code continues to run as shown in my for loop example above.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Yeah actually I thought my code is running top to bottom as a series. I will do this "async.parallel" option and if there's any other issue, will post a comment here :) Thanks for the HELP

Comment: Do you know why I can't access "userArray[i].ID" value ?

Comment: @RootSL using `i` is a common problem when performing async actions in node. The solution is to wrap it in a closure like so:

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            // do stuff
        })(i);
    }

Comment: Oh, this is a simple solution. I will try this too. It's better if this works for me. I'm really fed up with this issue :(

Comment: @MattAltepeter will ask anything if I need some more assistance :)

Comment: @MattAltepeter Hi, your theory worked well. Now it's working fine :) Thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool library called **ES6-promise-pool**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool

So it has concurrency option
Like:

```
var count = 0
var promiseProducer = function () {
  if (count < 5) {
    count++
    return delayValue(count, 1000)
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

var pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer, 3)

pool.start()
  .then(function () {
    console.log('Complete')
  })
```